# What is the best way to get Dataframe Abstraction over HBase Data without Pheonix

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to save and read the data from HBase from/to Spark.

I want to get the Dataframe abstraction as dataframe is best for memory management compared to RDD and it is convenient to do any processing.

I looked at possible candidates for getting Dataframe abstraction. One of them is Phoenix based solution. I do not want to have pheonix layer on top of HBase due to approvals. I searched for other solutions, but would want to know the best possibility that someone had tried.

Answer (score 0):

We have a performant one at Splice Machine (Open Source).  We wrote a separate InputFormat for HBase so we can read directly from store files in hbase vs. performing remote scans.  The killer for Spark performance on top of hbase is the remote scan based InputFormat (i.e. how you read the data).

Sean Busbey at Cloudera has worked on a Spark HBase connector and here is a blog from HortonWorks on a similar idea...

http://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/

The "connectors" functionally work but perform poorly for large data sets.

Hope this helps and good luck.